# Using the $_POST method between pages

Tags: php, forms, post, foreach

I have three separate PHP pages. On the first page, I pull information out of my database using the `'keywords'` column, which I turn into checkboxes:

```
$i=0;
foreach(explode(',', $keywords) as $keyword) {
    if($keyword != ""){
        $keyword = trim($keyword);
        $chkname = "checkbox{$i}";
        $i = $i+1;
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chkboxes[]" value="'.$keyword.'" id="chk_'.$keyword.'" />
                <label for="chk_'.$keyword.'">'.$keyword.'</label>'."<br />";
```

Then I pass this information into the second PHP script, which displays the checkboxes that a user actually checkmarks:

```
if(isset($_POST['chkboxes'])) {
  foreach($_POST['chkboxes'] as $chkbox) {
        echo '- '.$chkbox."<br />";
```

On the third PHP script, I want to grab the checkboxes that the user has checkmarked, and echo them out. For some reason I can't figure out, I can't grab the checkboxes that were checked. I've tried adding a hidden input field on the second php page,

```
if(isset($_POST['chkboxes'])) {
  foreach($_POST['chkboxes'] as $chkbox) {
        echo '- '.$chkbox."<br />";
        '<input type="hidden" name="options[]" id="options" value=" ' . $chkbox . '"/>';
  }
```

and on the thrid PHP script used:

```
if(isset($_POST['options'])){
    $options = $_POST['options'];
}
```

I don't know where to go from here. ANY help would be appreciated and I will select the correct answer. for now, on the third php page, I've been using `print_r($_POST);` to see what happens. Everything works, except it's not posting the checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sessions in this case. See: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Btw: Did you submit your hidden inputs?

Comment: Can you give an example? I've been trying with a $_SESSION, and it still isn't working. And yes, I did submit hidden inputs. It works if I take the value out of the foreach loop with $_POST, however, it only displays the last item checked. Not sure where to begin with this nightmare.